# Получить биты из строки

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, строки, память

Мне необходимо реализовать а блочный алгоритм шифрования Shacal, но я не знаю как из введённой строки получить биты. Хочу попытаться реализовать свой алгоритм на JavaScript

Comment: Нашел для вас (и уже для себя, так как заинтересовало) информацию: читайте [тут](https://habr.com/company/ruvds/blog/338150/) и [тут](https://habr.com/post/276957/) , спасибо за хороший вопрос (+1).

Comment: И как же выглядит введённая строка?

Comment: Строка может быть любого вида, число, слово или содержать и число и букву